# TensorFlow No image found in category validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, training-data

I am using TensorFlow library in python. I am trying to retrain my own image dataset for get prediction result from my trained image. I am following [this](http://[1]:%20https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0) tutorial.I am getting some error as "My_image_folder" has no image in category validation and division by zero, although "My_image_folder" contains images inside flower_photos folder when i was using following commands -

```
python -m scripts.retrain \
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
  --how_many_training_steps=500 \
  --model_dir=tf_files/models/ \
  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
  --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

There was 10 images in My_image_folder and all are in jpeg/jpg format which contains every image size less than 2 MB.

Is there any predefined image format, image size, memory issues etc for training using above tutorial ?

why i am getting error in category validation ? please help me out. i have been stuck with it for a long time.

Comment: Do you just need `--image_dir=My_image_folder/flower_photos` instead of `--image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos`? Or try an absolute path if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify **retrain.py** to ensure there is at least one image in the directory, as referenced [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2072). I haven't tested the impact on training, but it will allow you to run an end-to-end test without failing.

Edit this (around line 220):

```
  if percentage_hash < validation_percentage:
    validation_images.append(base_name)
  elif percentage_hash < (testing_percentage + validation_percentage):
    testing_images.append(base_name)
  else:
  ...
```

Like this:

```
  if len(validation_images) == 0:
     validation_images.append(base_name)
  elif percentage_hash < validation_percentage:
    validation_images.append(base_name)
  elif percentage_hash < (testing_percentage + validation_percentage):
    testing_images.append(base_name)
  else:
  ...
```